# Publish library into maven repository but not JCenter

Tags: bintray

I have **uploaded a library into bintray and have linked it to JCenter**, so it's accessible through jcenter global repo.

My issue is **there are some alpha or beta versions I don't want them to be at JCenter.**

Is it possible to **exclude some versions not to be linked into JCenter**?

Comment: i hope this link to help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588342/can-i-remove-a-library-from-jcenter

Comment: Thanks not exactly my issue, mine is one level behind, but thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When a package is linked to Jcenter. it goes there to stay**... So when you have linked your package to Jcenter, you can't separate versions (as far as I know).

One way to solve your issue is to **define a beta repo for your beta packages**.

So when you want to upload a beta version, target your beta repo and publish it there.

So stable versions will be published to Jcenter and beta ones will be available through beta channel.